# How to force a endpoint which takes files as base64 strings to stream?

Tags: retrofit, okhttp, moshi

I have a 3rd party (sort of) end point which accepts images as base64 strings in a json. Obviously this will lead to timeouts etc.

Is there a some magical way (some server config etc) to turn this into streamed upload as if it were a file? Or will regular multipart upload need to be implemented

Comment: What is the actual format? Ultimately you can always encode the whole JSON as a stream, including the values in a quoted string.

Look at the OutputStream method of https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html

So yes, but likely just a clunky manual method.  Depends on the JSON library or if you just write the json bytes directly.

Comment: @Yuri Schimke I'm using Moshi. As for the format, its a regular HTTP POST with json body. So you're saying I should be able to just add @ Multipart in retrofit and then pass in a custom RequestBody which uses the json as source and writes into sink?

Comment: Not sure. But if your motivated enough to stream the uploads it could work at OkHttp level if not higher.

Comment: Yea I'm motivated, however, backend needs to be modified as well? I naively expect it to build up a buffer of the streamed content, and then parse the json as a whole and do whatever it does next, right?

Comment: I would assume so.

Comment: What always confuses is that its Multipart/form-data, and In my mind form-data is exclusive to json body